# Understanding the proof of : If $G$ is a group of order $p^n$ and $X$ is a finite G-set then $|X|=|X_G| \space (\text{mod} \ p)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$$|X| = \sum_i^r |Gx_i|$$ is clear. Where $Gx_i = x \space \text{ such that} \space gx_i = x$ Now these are the orbits in $X$ under $G$. Clearly, equation above could be rewritten as follows since some orbits will consist of just one element only :

$$|X|=|X_G| + \sum_{i=s+1}^r |Gx_i| \ (*)$$
where  $X_G = x  \ \text{ such that} \  gx=x \   \forall g \in G$

> **Theorem :** Let $G$ be a group of order $p^n$ and let $X$ be a finite $G-set$. Then $|X|=|X_G| \ (\text{mod} \space p)$
>   In $(*)$ we know that $|Gx_i|$ divides $|G|$. Consequently $p$ divides $|Gx_i|$ for $s+1 \le i \le r$. Then $|X|-|X_G|$ is divisible by $p$ so the result follows.

I have no problem with $|Gx_i|$ dividing $|G|$. Since there is a one to one correspondence between $|Gx_i|$ and the cosets of isotropy subgroups of $G$. But how do we conclude that $p$ divides $|Gx_i|$??

Comment: $|G|=p^n$. What are the possible divisors of $p^n$? Don't forget that $p$ is prime.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown $1,p,p^2,...,p^n$. Any subgroup should have these orders, but could also have the order $p^n$ so left cosets would consist of $1$ element only. In this case $p$ does not divide $|Gx_i|$

Comment: @Xenidia But $|Gx_i| > 1$, because the orbits with only one elements are considered separately (in the $X_G$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write (fill in details)

$$|X|=\sum_{x\in X}|\mathcal Orb(x)|=\overbrace{1+1+...}^{=|X_G|}+\sum_{x\in X\setminus X_G}|\mathcal Orb(x)|=|X_G|\pmod p$$

where the $\;1+1+...\;$ part represents the orbits of elements in X that belong to $\;X_G\;$ , and since

$$x\in X\setminus X_g\implies |\mathcal Orb(x)|=[G:Stab_G(x)|$$

and the last index must be a positive power of $\;p\;$...